# Imacros - Extract and select multiple items from selector via predefined variable

Tags: extract, imacros

I'm trying to EXTRACT some content from a table to be used for selecting items on a select multiple box.

This works fine:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple
FRAME NAME="iframeResult"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/action_page.php ATTR=NAME:cars CONTENT=%volvo:%opel
```

How come that when creating the extract content as a variable, then it does not work:

The variable called `SET CARS volvo:%opel`

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple
FRAME NAME="iframeResult"
SET CARS volvo:%opel
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/action_page.php ATTR=NAME:cars CONTENT=%{{CARS}}
```

Error message:

`Entry [volvo:%opel] not available [Box has 4 entries], line: 6 (Error code: -924)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition I can suggest another way:

```
' ... '
FRAME NAME="iframeResult"
SET CARS "volvo,opel"
EVENT TYPE=CLICK XPATH=EVAL("'//HTML/BODY/FORM/SELECT/OPTION[@value=\\'' + '{{CARS}}'.split(',')[0] + '\\']';") BUTTON=0 MODIFIERS="ctrl"
EVENT TYPE=CLICK XPATH=EVAL("'//HTML/BODY/FORM/SELECT/OPTION[@value=\\'' + '{{CARS}}'.split(',')[1] + '\\']';") BUTTON=0 MODIFIERS="ctrl"
```

---

According to the [wiki documentation](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG) you have to write the code like this:

```
' ... '
FRAME NAME="iframeResult"
SET CAR1 "volvo"
SET CAR2 "opel"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/action_page.php ATTR=NAME:cars CONTENT=%{{CAR1}}:%{{CAR2}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it is not exactly what I'm looking for as I have an arbitrary number of values.

Comment: No problem. The [JavaScript Scripting Interface](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface) will help you perfectly in this case.

Comment: Just looked around and it seams like it is no longer possible to access the DOM from within Imacros for Firefox any longer :-(

Comment: Guess URL GOTO could be used as a hack... Will have to try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608734/how-do-i-set-the-select-all-checkbox-imacros-without-using-the-button-play-l

Answer (score 0):

Found a way using the script interface. Simply add the list of items to select usign JS:

```
function createMultiSelector(list) {
    macro = "CODE:";
    macro += "URL GOTO=https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple\n";
    macro += "FRAME = 'iframeResult'\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/action_page.php ATTR=NAME:cars CONTENT=%"+list+"\n";
    iret = iimPlay(macro);
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more useful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do.